# Python PyGithub how to list projectCard?

Tags: python, pygithub

I'm trying to access project card from github api with PyGithub but I'm unable to find how to call the projectcard method (https://developer.github.com/v3/projects/cards/)
It seems to be ready to use (https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/ProjectCard.html)
My code working for projects :

```
from github import Github

# github access token
g = Github("XXXXX")

repo = g.get_repo("Myrepo")
projects = repo.get_projects(state='open')
for project in projects:
    print('do something with project')
```

thanks a lot in advance

Comment: what do you get ? Empty screen or error message? Always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you can use `dir()` to check functions avaliable in object - `print( dir(project) )` - maybe there is function for card. I don't have projects to test it.

Comment: [Project](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Project.html) has `get_columns()` and [ProjectColumn](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/ProjectColumn.html) has `get_cards()`. Maybe this is method which you need.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your help
get_cards on columns solve the problem.